# PowerApps : interogating datasources

Tags: powerapps

I have a text label in a budget form, I used to create my document title. This title is like : "BU[YEAR]-001".

When my users save the document, I want to take the year, find the highest existed document, add one, and save.

Exemple : my datasources contains BU2018-001, BU2019-001 and BU2019-002.
If my user select 2019 in year label, and save the document, I want the title to be BU2019-003. If it's 2018 => BU2018-002 and if the year not exist, like 2020 => BU2020-001.

Using : LookUp(Budget2.Title;Text(Annee) in Title;Title), I can restrain to my budget with the year in it, but it only take the first one.

Can you help me with this, please?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you found out, [LookUp](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-filter-lookup) only returns one item, in no specific order (likely the first one that was entered, but this is not guaranteed). If you want a specific record (the last one), you can first [sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-sort) the source in descending order, then take the [first](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-first-last) element from the sorted result:

```
First(
    SortByColumns(
        Filter(
            Budget2;
            Text(Annee) in Title);
        "Title";
        Descending)).Title
```